# How to send data between two already configured HC-05 modules pi pico

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm building an small project in which I'd like to send information from a master HC-05 bluetooth module to an slave one (both of them connected to different pi pico's), I've already synced them following [Bluetooth HC-05 master-slave configuration using CircuitPython](https://tutorial.cytron.io/2022/05/31/bluetooth-hc-05-master-slave-configuration-using-circuitpython/) tutorial, I've finished the set up and now both modules (master and slave) seem to be properly connected, now the problem is that I don't know how to send data from one to the other.

All the tutorials that I've found that imply bluetooth communication seem to do it from a mobile Android app to the slave module, but what I'd like to do is to read data from an analog joystick with one pi pico and send it to through my master HC-05 the slave module (which would be connected to another pico) and then control an electric motor with this received data.

As I understand, the configuration process was finished in CircuitPython but this DOES NOT obligate me to continue with CircuitPython, I mean, I could do my implementation with microPython for example as Circuit Python was used only for the configuration process, is this correct?

My main question is, what is the library/process I could use to send data from master module to slave module?

Pd: I know there is a Raspberry Stack Exchange site but I posted my question here for visibility and also it is related to software too!.

Comment: I don't have any HC05s to play with, but `hc05.write()` and `hc05.readline()` would be my guess.

Comment: @MarkSetchell you were right, it was a little more complex than that but it worked, thanks man!